# Use fmt:formatDate (or other) to output timestamp since epoch

Tags: java, jsp, datetime, formatting, jstl

I need to print the timestamp since epoch on a JSP page. So far I have:

```
<jsp:useBean id="now" class="java.util.Date" />
<fmt:formatDate value="${now}"/>
```

The problem with this is that my default output for `formatDate` `May 29, 2013`, and the syntax available for the `pattern` doesn't appear to have anything like [strftime](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?strftime+3)'s `%s`.

What's the tersest way for me to get a timestamp in seconds or milliseconds in JSP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call [`Date#getTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29). It returns the epoch time in millis.

```
${now.time}
```

Or if you want it in seconds,

```
${now.time / 1000}
```